# get path of recursive for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

here i am having a sample dataframe

```
test_list = [['male','pack','lower'], ['male','nonpack','upper'], ['female','pack','upper'], ['male','pack','middle'], ['female','nonpack','middle']]
df1=pd.DataFrame(test_list, columns=['gender', 'subscription', 'ageCategory'])
```

[image]

the output which i need is

```
 gender-male|subscription-pack|ageCategory-lower
 gender-male|subscription-pack|ageCategory-upper
 gender-male|subscription-pack|ageCategory-middle
 gender-male|subscription-nonpack|ageCategory-lower
 gender-male|subscription-nonpack|ageCategory-upper
 gender-male|subscription-nonpack|ageCategory-middle
 gender-female|subscription-pack|ageCategory-lower
 gender-female|subscription-pack|ageCategory-upper
 gender-female|subscription-pack|ageCategory-middle
 gender-female|subscription-nonpack|ageCategory-lower
 gender-female|subscription-nonpack|ageCategory-upper
 gender-female|subscription-nonpack|ageCategory-middle
```

the recursive function which I wrote to obtain the  o/p

```
global name_list
name_list = []
global flag
flag=1
list_tuples = []
def do_calcuations1(iteration_list, level, df1, length=None):
    global name
    global flag
    if level < 3:       
        name_list.append(iteration_list[level])
        catogries = df1[iteration_list[level]].unique()
        for cata in catogries:
            name_list.append("-"+str(cata))   
            df2 = df1[df1[iteration_list[level]] == cata]
            do_calcuations1(iteration_list, level + 1, df2, len(catogries))
            name_list.pop()
    else:
        if level == 3:          
            print("the name from list is ", "|".join(name_list))
            info = (name, df1)
            list_tuples.append(info)         
            if length == flag:
                name_list.pop()
            else:
                flag += 1
        pass
iteration_list=['gender', 'subscription', 'ageCategory']
do_calcuations1(iteration_list,0,df1)
```

the output that I am getting is

```
 gender|-male|subscription|-pack|ageCategory|-lower
  gender|-male|subscription|-pack|ageCategory|-middle
  gender|-male|subscription|-nonpack|ageCategory|-upper
  gender|-male|subscription|-female|subscription|-pack|ageCategory|-upper
  gender|-male|subscription|-female|subscription|-pack|-nonpack|ageCategory|-middle
```

I am trying to save each unique data frame and its path as  a tuple and appending it to a list
can anyone show me the right approach to do this, Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your output required, you want to remove ageCategory of middle?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add middle i will update it

Comment: @azizshaw what is your input? Do you initially have the categories?

Comment: @mozway yes,  the output mush have the key as  eg:-  "gender-male|subscription-pack|ageCategory-lower" and the value to be the data frame filtered according to the condition of key

Comment: @azizshaw this is not my question. Do you have a dataframe as input or a list/dictionary?

Comment: as an input CSV to display an example I have taken sample values  as list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` to create cartesian product of 3 columns:

```
s = (pd.MultiIndex.from_product([("gender-"+df1["gender"]).unique(),
                                   ("subscription-"+df1["subscription"]).unique(),
                                   ("ageCategory-"+df1["ageCategory"]).unique()],
                                  names=df1.columns)
       .to_frame(False))

print (s)

           gender          subscription         ageCategory
0     gender-male     subscription-pack   ageCategory-lower
1     gender-male     subscription-pack   ageCategory-upper
2     gender-male     subscription-pack  ageCategory-middle
3     gender-male  subscription-nonpack   ageCategory-lower
4     gender-male  subscription-nonpack   ageCategory-upper
5     gender-male  subscription-nonpack  ageCategory-middle
6   gender-female     subscription-pack   ageCategory-lower
7   gender-female     subscription-pack   ageCategory-upper
8   gender-female     subscription-pack  ageCategory-middle
9   gender-female  subscription-nonpack   ageCategory-lower
10  gender-female  subscription-nonpack   ageCategory-upper
11  gender-female  subscription-nonpack  ageCategory-middle

# As key vs value pairs:
print ({"|".join(y.iloc[0]): y for _, y in s.groupby(level=0)})
```

Comment: thanks, however I am trying to get  it as key-value pair  
the key would be like "gender-male|subscription-pack|ageCategory-lower" and the value will be the dataframe corresponding to the condition

Comment: I don't get the value part. What dataframe corresponding to the condition?

Comment: so the keys is eg: "gender-male|subscription-pack|ageCategory-lower"   for this key the value will be  dataframe that  should contain only  (gender as male )and (subscription should be pack ) and (ageCategory should as lower )

Comment: Rather strange output but i have updated in above @azizshaw.

Comment: thanks the dataset that I am working on has around 1800000 rows  so for each condition I am creating a tuple containing a key  as a condition that is applied and the value as  a dataframe

Comment: I think it makes more sense to store just the key and only create a df when you need to process, but it’s up to you.

Comment: okay  so I can store the key as a list and then process the data frame parallelly according to the keys